# Crash due to unwrapping values from api (using Alamofire)

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I have this struct to parse values from my api..

```
struct Deals {
    let title: String
    let detail: String

init(title : String, detail: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.detail = detail

}
}
```

Now I'm parsing the data from Alamofire in this format...

```
     if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {

            if let result = response.result.value as? [String:Any] {
              guard let top = orderData["data"] as? [Any] else {
                                            return
               }
           for value in top {
             let aDict = value as? [String : Any]

             let title = aDict!["title"] as? String

             let detail = aDict!["description"] as? String

              let theDeals = Deals(title: title!, detail: detail!)
}
}
}
```

But some of these values have a nil value from server(for eg.detail is nil from server) and so it is causing a crash. I'm having difficulty using an `if let` properly so that the crash can be handled. Hope somebody can help...

Comment: In which line your app is crashing

Comment: in this line `let detail = aDict!["...`

Comment: don't use unwrapping then see the answer below of @CZ54

Comment: your data contains nil value but in code you using unwrapping that means it must contain value thats the reason your app is crashing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are unwrapping the `dict` even if the parsing fail. 
Update to :

```
 if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {


      guard let result = response.result.value as? [String:Any],
                let top = orderData["data"] as? [Any]
                else { return }

       for value in top {
        if  let aDict = value as? [String : Any],
            let title = aDict["title"] as? String,
            let detail = aDict["description"] as? String {
                let theDeals = Deals(title: title, detail: detail)
        } else {
        //parsing failed
        }
       }
  }
```